# Raphael.js how to set attribute for a path?

Tags: javascript, raphael

In Raphael.js, If I have a path object, I would like to reset the attribute, how to do it?

```
myPath.attr('M', VALUE_FOR_M)
      .attr('L', VALUE_FOR_L);
```

seems not working...

Comment: @Joachim, why shouldn't I think so???? Of course I know Raphael is not jQuery. Raphael also provide attr() method to set attribute for element. If you check Raphael documentation on its official website. http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#attr

Comment: However, reading the linked documentation shows that `M` or `L` are not listed in the possible parameters.

Comment: Yes, that's why I ask here how to set attribute for path, since there is no reference for that.

Comment: as far as I understand `M` and `L` are not **atributes** of a path, they are simply elements that can exist in its specification. They can also exist **multiple times** so "changing their value" doesn't really make a lot of sense. Could you post an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6):

you do it like this:

```
var newPath = ["M", VALUE_FOR_M_X, VALUE_FOR_M_Y, 
               "L", VALUE_FOR_L_X, VALUE_FOR_L_Y];

myPath.attr({ path : newPath });
```

newPath is a pathString (see [SVG path string format](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData))

Comment: This seems like a better solution, you do not loose any other attributes that have been saved onto path when it was created.

Comment: Can you actually just use the array like that? Or do you have to `.join(' ')` it to make a string?

Comment: @TimErickson Both is casted to a string. The difference is only that the implicit casting will result in a comma separated value string and your solution in a space separated value string. "M,1,1,L,1,1" vs "M 1 1 L 1 1"

Answer (score 3):

To create a path, I prefer,

```
var myPath = paper.path(['M', M_VAL0, M_VAL1, 
                         'L', L_VAL0, L_VAL1].join(' '));
myPath.insertAfter(nodewhatever);
```

It makes your actions much easier to follow.

to update your path,

```
myPath.remove();
myPath = paper.path(['M', M_VAL2, M_VAL3, 
                     'L', L_VAL2, L_VAL3].join(' '));
myPath.insertAfter(nodewhatever);
```

Is this what you wanted to do?